# Why can't we measure the different components of angular momentum simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Why can't we measure the different components of angular momentum simultaneously? I want a physical explanation. (I know that they don't commute with each other).

Comment: If you've worked out the QM commutation relations for the the various components of angular momentum (AM), then you know that the reason that the AM components don't commute (and, hence, cannot be measured simultaneously) directly derives from the fact that position and (linear) momentum components don't commute. So are you really asking for a "physical explanation" of why position and the linear momentum in a given direction can't be measured simultaneously?

Comment: What is the argument which satisfies you for the impossibility of simultaneous measurement of position and momentum? It might make it clearer what are you looking for here.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you define the states $\{|l \rangle\}$ as the eigenstates of the operator $L_z$, that is $L_z|l\rangle  = l |l\rangle$. Any operator $O$ that *commutes* with $L_z$ has the same eigenstates, indeed

$$
L_z (O|l\rangle) = O(L_z|l\rangle) = O(l |l\rangle) = l (O|l\rangle)
$$

that means that $O|l\rangle$ must be an eigenstate of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $l$.

Now, if on the other hand $O$ *does not commute* with $L_z$, the result of $O|l_z\rangle$ will be any other state, in general a linear combination of $\{|l\rangle\}$ but . This means that

$$
O |l\rangle = \sum_{l'} c_{l'}|l'\rangle \not= l |l\rangle
$$

With this in mind, imagine a system you prepared in the eigenstate $l$ of $L_z$, and the next two situations

- Measure $L_z$ and then $L_x$: In the first step you get $l$ and the system stays in the state $|l\rangle$. Then, when you measure $L_x$, the wavefunction will collapse to any of the eigenstates of $L_x$ which are different from $|l\rangle$
- Measure $L_x$ and then $L_z$: In the first step the measure will leave the system in any of the eigenstates of $L_x$, and then when you measure $L_z$ it will give you any of the eigenstates of $L_z$, different from $|l\rangle$

So you measuring these two observables in different order, will yield different answers, in other words, you cannot hope to measure both simultaneously and get the same answer

Comment: Can you explain it in terms of rotation using Euler's angels ?